# Rational solution to $X^3 -6X -6 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

So I have to prove that there is no rational solution to the Polynomial (I dont know if I spelled it correctly it's Polynôme in french)
$ X^3 - 6X -6 = 0 $
I know that i have to suppose that there exists a rational solution for the polynomial and then find a contradiction but I tried almost every trick up my sleeve and I haven't been able to prove it.
I thought that I could demonstrate by supposing that a/b (two integers) is the rational solution Gcd(a,b) =1 and then finding a common divisor [I don't know the English terms very well] but i just can't progress using this classical method.
I'm in terminal highschool if you want to know my level.
P.s: thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the rational root test (also called "the rational zero theorem"). Check your textbook for the details.

Comment: You can brute force this by applying the [Rational Zero Theorem](https://www.sparknotes.com/math/algebra2/polynomials/section4/). Those are all of the *possible* rational zeros, which means if none of them apply, then there are *no* rational zeros at all.

Comment: Rational root test, I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with this method

Comment: But if it's an assigned problem, then most likely, it's in your textbook.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: It is not an assigned question unfortunately just a sort of optional exercice

Comment: At a slightly more advanced level you can argue that  $\mathbb Z$ is integrally closed (like all UFD's) so that every rational zero of a monic polynomial with integral coefficients is automatically an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the equation $x^3 - 6x -6 = 0$ has a rational root ${\large{\frac{p}{q}}}$, where $p,q$ are integers with $\gcd(p,q)=1$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}&\;\;x^3-6x-6=0
\qquad\qquad\;\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\left({\small{\frac{p}{q}}}\right)^3-6\left({\small{\frac{p}{q}}}\right)-6=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&p^3-6pq^2-6q^3=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&p^3=2(3pq^2+3q^3)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence $p$ must be even, so we can write $p=2s$, for some integer $s$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}&\;\;p^3-6pq^2-6q^3=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;\;&(2s)^3-6(2s)q^2-6q^3=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;\;&8s^3-12sq^2-6q^3=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;\;&3q^3=2(2s^3-3sq^2)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence $q$ must be even, contradiction, since $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

Thus, the given equation has no rational roots.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways of solving this, including using general results. Here is a direct method. Let $X=\frac ab$ be a fraction in lowest terms, with $b\gt 0$. Then $a^3-6ab^2-6b^3=0$ so that $$a^3=6b^2(a+b)$$ from which it follows that $a$ is divisible by both $2$ and $3$ as well as any prime factor of $b$. But we assumed that $a$ and $b$ had no common factors, so $b$ is positive and has no prime factors, so we must have $b=1$.

[Note that this argument can be carried out for any polynomial where the coefficient of the highest power of $x$ is equal to $1$ - you can pull out a factor of $b$ from the lower terms and get that a multiple of $b$ is equal to a power of $a$. In such a case any rational root is an integer. Then we can use the factor theorem for polynomials to show that any integer root divides the constant term - which is the substance of the rational root test applied to monic polynomials - it is not a scary thing]

So we can go back to the original equation and simply assume now that $X=a$ is an integer. Then $$X^3=6(X+1)$$

$X$ must be even, because the right-hand side is, but $X+1$ is odd. $X^3$ is divisible by $8$ and $6(x+1)$ is not.

Comment: it seems my method wasn't of the tracks I just didn't notice that B must be equal to 1, the method proposed by quasi is very useful and short aswell, I've looked the rational root test in wikipedia but it is not within our program but is still very useful,  I suppose they wanted us to use the gcd contradiction, but this method is also a brilliant way to do it

Comment: In math, don't assume "what they want you to use". Learn to think for yourself, and find ways to get to the result one way or another. Once, we got a math problem, and I solved it very creatively with matrix equations. The teacher assumed I had copied the method from somewhere, and graded me a C (only because it was correct). But he asked me where I had found the method, and I said I had invented it myself. He was impressed and gave me an A. It was not in our curriculum!

Answer (score 0):

There's a *rational roots theorem*, which may no be in your curriculum, in which case you can prove it, then use it:

> Let $f(x)=c_nx^n+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+c_1x+c_0\enspace(c_n\ne 0)\;$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. If $a/b$ is a rational root in irreducible form, then $a$ divides the constant term $c_0$ and $b$ divides the leading coefficient $c_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to solve the equation and find the actual root.

To prove that the equation has exactly 1 root, notice that by differentiating the function f(x) = x^3 - 6x - 6, you'll know where the local maximum and minimum are. f'(x) = 3x^2 - 6 = 0 eq. x = +/- 2^(1/2). The negative value is at a local maximum, the positive value at a local minimum, since f is positive for x >> 0. You can determine that f(-2^(1/2)) < 0 and f(2^(1/2)) > 0. This leads to the conclusion that the equation has only 1 real root.

Applying a solution method, you can find that the only root is equal to 2^(1/3) + 4^(1/3), but you can check this without ado. This root is clearly not rational.

Comment: I rather think that proving this polynomial has no rationa roots is the way to prove that $\root3\of2+\root3\of4$ is irrational. It is not immediately clear that this sum of cube roots is irrational *without a suitable piece of extra theory*. Besides, the polynomial has three roots in $\Bbb{C}$. This is the only real root.

Comment: I can prove that x = 2^(1/3) + 4^(1/3) is not rational "without a suitable piece of extra theory", qualifying my earlier answer beyond reproach.

Since x = (2^(1/3) + 4^(1/3))^3 is a root of the original equation, x^3 = 6x + 1, let's assume that x = p/q with (p,q) = 1 and q <> 0. 
We see that (p/q)^3 = (p/q) + 1 eq. p^3/q^2 = p + q, an integer! This means that q^2 must have prime factors of p^3, hence of p. But then, q has prime factors in common with p, or q = 1. Hence, q = 1. But that means that x should be an integer, which it clearly isn't (any approximation). Hence, x is not rational.

Comment: Yes, the rational root theorem is exactly what I had in mind (IIRC).